# Set message for two unique fields

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to set a custom error message on both a username and an email field when the is_unique validation check fails.

```
$this->form_validation->set_message('is_unique', 'Username already registered, please log in!');

$this->form_validation->set_message('is_unique', 'Email already registered, please log in!');
```

How will codeigniter decipher between the two? I've consulted the user guide and haven't found a solution. Is there a way to tell it the is_unique is for the username and then the next one is for the email?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that. Just go about it a different way, and include `%s` in your error message.

```
$this->form_validation->set_message('is_unique', '%s already registered, please log in!');
```

Via CodeIgniter:

> If you include %s in your error string, it will be replaced with the
>   "human" name you used for your field when you set your rules.

Source: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html#settingerrors

Comment: Perfect, missed that in the documentation! Works a treat!

Comment: Is it possible to print the input value entered? e.g email@example.com already registered.